# How do you explain that Poynting's theorem $P=E\times H$ is still valid for DC fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, poynting-vector

Poynting's theorem P = ExH is quite valid for DC circuits with stationary electromagnetic fields as well as for AC circuits and time varying EM fields.  The question arises: Do Maxwell's 4 equations have any significance in stationary electromagnetic fields? i.e. when the time derivative of both E&H is zero?We assume that the proof(s) of mathematical physics exist but should be based on groundbreaking assumptions.
NB: There is no relationship between Maxwell's 4 equations and the Lorentz force F=q(E+vxB) which are two different and totally independent phenomena equations.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: – 
Community
Bot . Thank you for your useful comment .Clarification is added.

Answer (score 1):

> Do Maxwell's 4 equations have any significance in stationary electromagnetic fields? i.e. when the time derivative of both E&H is zero?

Yes. Maxwell’s equations and the Lorentz force law describe all classical behavior of the electric and magnetic fields and their interactions with charges. They apply for all frequencies, including zero.

Their only limitation is that they are classical, they require large enough pieces of matter that things can be treated classically. Although, for the fields the Schrodinger’s equation reproduces Maxwell’s equations anyway. So Maxwell’s equations do play a non-trivial role even quantum mechanically.

So, the short answer is, yes. Poynting’s theorem does apply at DC and even at DC the Poynting vector represents energy flux. The flow of energy from a battery to a resistive load can be analyzed with it.

To see this, first consider the DC Maxwell's equations $$ \nabla \cdot \vec D = \rho $$  $$ \nabla \cdot \vec B = 0 $$  $$ \nabla \times \vec E = 0 $$  $$ \nabla \times \vec H = \vec J $$ where $\rho$ and $\vec J$ are specifically the free charge and current densities. Now, we can combine the third and fourth equations as follows: $$ \vec H \cdot \left(\nabla \times \vec E \right) + \vec E \cdot \left(\nabla \times \vec H \right) = \vec E \cdot \vec J $$ which simplifies to $$\nabla \cdot \left( \vec E \times \vec H \right) + \vec E \cdot \vec J = 0$$ which applies for time-independent scenarios. Unsurprisingly, this is what we would have obtained using Poynting's theorem directly and removing all of the time-dependent terms.

Comment: Dale-Thank you for your helpful response.
But the question arises:
Assuming Maxwell's equations Curl H=J+dD/dt)partial and Curl E=-dB/dt)partial apply to all frequencies including zero.
Can you please write the above equations when the frequency is zero, so the time derivative of D&B is zero?

Comment: @Lionheart sure, I just added it

Comment: Dale-Thanks again for your helpful response.
But excuse me, I don't see a complete improvement in your re-edited answer.
In fact the current density J or better named Jc represents the conduction current of free charges which vanishes in free space.
I can see that you are considering a DC circuit, but in this case we need to describe the circuit and its E&H fields.
However, this produces evidence but not rigorous proof.

Comment: @Lionheart it is a rigorous proof. The first step is just linearly combining the 3rd and 4th equations. The second step is a vector identity. It is completely rigorous. Yes, clearly $J=0$ in free space. I am not sure why that is a concern to you here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "groundbreaking assumptions" but I think you mean "experimental evidence"?

Poyntings theorem is derived directly from maxwells equations, which is experimentally verified.

$$\vec{S} = \frac{1}{\mu_0}\vec{E} × \vec{B}$$

Is the poynting vector, not poyntings theorem.

Comment: jensen paull-Thank you for your helpful response.
But the question arises:
Do Maxwell's 4 equations have any significance in stationary electromagnetic fields?
i.e. when the time derivative of both E&H is zero?

Comment: Maxwells equations apply equally as well for stationary fields. The poynting vectors divergence for stationary fields in freespace is zero  such that the energy leaving a region is the same as the energy entering a region